# NVarChar for MySQL in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I use this INSERT to add new record to database. But it can not show the Vietnamese in correct form. (Ex: Kh?ch s?n instead of Khách sạn).

How can I add "N" to the query in this case.

```
if (general.TestEmail.IsEmail(txt_Email.Text) == true)
            {
                //Insert dữ liệu vào database
                email = txt_Email.Text;
                MySqlCommand them_hotel = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO quan_li.hotel (name, star, address, province, phone, fax, email) VALUES (@name, @star, @address, @province, @phone, @fax, @email)");
                them_hotel.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                them_hotel.Connection = conn_class.connection;
             //   them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hid", txt_Hid.Text);
                them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txt_Ten.Text);
                them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@star", txt_Sao.Text);
                them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txt_DiaChi.Text);
                them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@province", txt_Tinh.Text);
                them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", txt_DienThoai.Text);
                them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fax", txt_Fax.Text);
                them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txt_Email.Text);

                conn_class.OpenConnection();
                them_hotel.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn_class.CloseConnection();
                thanh_cong = "Đã thêm khách sạn thành công";
            }
            else
            {
                email_err = "Email không đúng định dạng \n";
            }
```

Thank you very much for you help !

**Solved:**

I add Charset=utf8 to my connection string.
This is mine

```
public void Initialize()
    {
        server = "localhost";
        database = "quan_li";
        uid = "root";
        password = "";
        string connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";" + "Charset=utf8";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
```

Comment: try and add like this to all parameters:                                           command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.nVarChar))value =txt_Ten.Text ;

Comment: Tell me if this worked for you...

Comment: @Pranav-BitWiser Do you mean this?
them_hotel.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
                    them_hotel.Parameters[0].Value = txt_Ten.Text;
There is an error: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: its should be like this:-    command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.nVarChar)).value =txt_Ten.Text ;    to this for all parameters...change the DataType when inserting to 'NVarchar'

Comment: @Pranav-BitWiserI found the solution, just add Charset=utf8 into the connection string.

Comment: bro you saved me, thanx